# Is it true that $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x+h) - 2f(x) = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}-f(x-h)$?

Tags: limits

If $f$ is a continuous function, is it valid for me to say that $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x+h) - 2f(x) = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}-f(x-h)$?

Comment: Hint: Since $f$ is continuous $\lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)=f(x)$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $\lim_{t \to 0} f(x+t) = f(x)$, so yes.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then both are equal to $-f(x)$, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** rewrite your equation as
$$
f(x)=\frac12\left(\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)+\lim_{h\to0}f(x-h)\right)
$$
Note that unless you specify $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}$ or$\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}$, you have $\lim\limits_{h\to0}f(x+h)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}f(x-h)$.